# Listview and baseadapter

Tags: android, listview

I have created listview using baseadapter.
I want to go to different activities when click on different items but not able to get item value.So anyone can help me how to do it.
For example on click on Item x i want to activity1
on clicking item say z,I want to go to avctivity2
Thank you.

Here is code:

```
    public class homeScreen extends Activity{
ListView list1; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);

        list1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.spacelist);
        list1.setAdapter(new MySimpleAdapter(this));
        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                Intent i=new Intent(homeScreen.this, privateSpaceList.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}

class SingleRow{

    String title;
    int image;
    public SingleRow(String title,int image) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.title=title;
        this.image=image;
    }
}
 class MySimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;
    public MySimpleAdapter(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context=c;
        list=new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
        //putting actual values in array
        Resources res=c.getResources();
        String[] titles=res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        int[] images={R.drawable.error,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};

        //putting single row in arraylist
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i], images[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return i;
    }

    //called when want to display row
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,viewgroup,false);
        TextView title=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        SingleRow temp=list.get(i);
        title.setText(temp.title);
        image.setImageResource(temp.image);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: set row layout clickable

Comment: You can make a switch on position value inside onItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your item click change your code to

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       String[] titles=res.getStringArray(R.array.titles); 
         if((titles[position]).equalsIgnoreCase("Itemx"))
         {
              Intent i=new Intent(homeScreen.this, privateSpaceList.class);
              startActivity(i);
         }
         else if((titles[position]).equalsIgnoreCase.equals("Itemy"))
         {
              Intent i=new Intent(homeScreen.this, activity2.class);
              startActivity(i);
         }
         else if((titles[position]).equalsIgnoreCase.equals("Itemz"))
         {
              Intent i=new Intent(homeScreen.this, activity3.class);
              startActivity(i);
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think easy way to implement **ClickListener** on **getView** in Adapter class. Or, in your case you need store **List<..>**, also this list you add to adapter, and in this moment:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long id) {   
  Intent intent = new Intent(homeScreen.this, privateSpaceList.class);
  yourList.get(position) // your data
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

You get your object.

or like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long id) {  

    switch(position) {

      case 1:
          Intent intent = new Intent(homeScreen.this, privateSpaceList.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          break;

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            TextView title=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.label);    
             if(title.getText().toString().trim().equals("Item x"))
             {
                  Intent i=new Intent(homeScreen.this, activity1.class);
                  startActivity(i);
             }
             else if(title.getText().toString().trim().equals("Item y"))
             {
                  Intent i=new Intent(homeScreen.this, activity2.class);
                  startActivity(i);
             }
             else if(title.getText().toString().trim().equals("Item z"))
             {
                  Intent i=new Intent(homeScreen.this, activity3.class);
                  startActivity(i);
             }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

**Its a very easy way to do without so much of conditions.**

Define a array of all your Activity class name. **But all activity should in the same package.**

```
String[] Classtitles=new String[]{"Activity1","Activity2","Activity3"};
```

**Get the Package Name**

```
final String packageName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
```

**And change inside the onItemClick()**

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long id) {
               try {
                        Class c = Class.forName(packageName + "." + Classtitles[position]);
                        startActivity(new Intent(homeScreen.this, c));
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(homeScreen.this, String.valueOf(e), 5000).show();
                    }
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you.